# Cocoapods Installation Not Going Through

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I had a problem regarding installing cocoapods on my mac. Below is my error code i got in my terminal.I don't know what i do wrong and what should i do to fix this.I already tried to google the same problem but nothing working out. Any help will be much appreciated. thank you.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:48: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        "/opt/local/bin/ruby" -rubygems /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.1/ext RUBYLIBDIR=/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.1/ext
/opt/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:68: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
checking for -std=c99 option to compiler... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/opt/local/bin/ruby
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `block in try_compile'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:443:in `with_werror'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `try_compile'
        from extconf.rb:24:in `block in <main>'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from extconf.rb:23:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/opt/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb...]

Tasks: TOP => default => ext
(See full trace by running task with --trace)


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.1/ext/xcodeproj/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Do `gem install rake` first - add `sudo` if you called the above with `sudo`.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but i still got the same error.

Comment: With `sudo` too? Are you doing `sudo gem install cocoapods`?

Comment: yes, i'm doing sudo install cocoapods.

Comment: Add the output of `gem list --local` to you question please, the we can see what your current gem installation is like :)

Comment: this is result for **gem list --local** :

`*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (3.2.17)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bundler (1.3.5)
claide (0.5.0)
cocoapods-core (0.32.1)
cocoapods-downloader (0.5.0)
colored (1.2)
fuzzy_match (2.0.4)
i18n (0.6.9)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.4)
json_pure (1.8.1)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.9.2)
nap (0.7.0)
rake (10.3.1, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
rubygems-update (2.2.2)`

Comment: Oh you've already got `cocoapods` installed. Try doing `gem uninstall rake`, `gem uninstall cocoapods`, `gem install cocoapods`

Comment: Oh! I've just noticed something in your error output, have you installed Xcode and its command line tools? To check `xcode-select --install`

Comment: I already tried `xcode-select --install` but i got this as result **xcode-select: Error: unknown command option '--install'.**. I also tried installing command line tools for xcode by doing _xcode->preferences->downloads->components->component line tools_ and when i give a command `xcode-select --version` it gave me **xcode-select version 2311**. I'm using mountain lion (10.8.5) @Rich

Comment: You can go [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and search for "_command_", you need the April 2014 ones. What version of Xcode do you have?

Comment: I  solved this issue by Symlinking llvm as gcc  in terminal : `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2` but i still got **/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:55: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777** after running pod command. @Rich